# How can I implement Laravel Eloquent wherehas count question?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, wherehas

I have bookings and addon table.

bookings has many addons.

I want to get bookings with addon type Optional Tour

I tried this

```
 $bookings = Booking::with([
        "add_ons",  
         ])
        ->whereHas("add_ons",function($q){
            $q->where("type","<>" ,AddOn::T_OPTIONAL_TOUR);
        })
```

which obviously not working.
how can i get only bookings with no optional tour addon?

here is table infomation

bookings

```
id
name
```

Booking_add_ons

```
id
booking_id
add_on_id
```

add_ons

```
id
type
add_name
```

Comment: well I think my question was not clear.

Comment: I need to get bookings with add ons where the addon has no optional tours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereDoesntHave()`:

```php
$bookings = Booking::with('add_ons')
    ->whereDoesntHave('add_ons', function($q) {
        $q->where('type', '=', AddOn::T_OPTIONAL_TOUR);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I had more where clauses which caused malfunctioning.